# Calculate the double integral: $\iint_D\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy$ with $D=\{(x,y)\in\ R^2:4y \le x^2+y^2; 4 \le x^2+y^2 \le 16; y \ge 0; x \ge 0\}$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am trying to solve the following double integral using polar coordinates:

$$\iint_D\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy$$
$$D=\{(x,y)\in\ R^2:4y \le x^2+y^2; 4 \le x^2+y^2 \le 16; y \ge 0; x \ge 0\}$$

But upon graphing the region represented by $D$, I am unable to determine the intervals as I am not sure how to work with the intersection of the two inner circles.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the point $P$ then the angle and separate the integral into the two separate regions.

[image]

Comment: I figured out the point in terms of $(x,y)$ but I am having trouble determining the polar values.

Comment: Use the relations $r^2=x^2+y^2,\,x=r\sin\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta$ and then converting the Cartesian equations into polar equations is straightforward. And if you know the coordinates of $P$ then you have the angle of the line containing  $(0,0)$ and $P$ given by $\phi=\arctan(y/x)$.

Comment: +1 for a useful hint without solving the problem for the OP.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I figured it out. Now, I have reached to the part where I divide the integral into two parts but how do I determine the interval of the line for the upper section of the region?

Comment: It will be between the polar equations of the inner and outer curves.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks. And what did you use to create the image of the intersection of the regions?

Comment: Desmos calculator. https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8bisjeopnt